# Is there a way to fetch and store images in one folder using two different laravel application?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

I have a user and an admin laravel application that are two separate file/app in my desktop. I want to store and display images that was upload from one application to another and vice versa. Is there a way to do that?

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/filesystem -- create a "disk" that both users have access to, and configure it properly.

Comment: can you elaborate?

Comment: Read the posted documentation. Also, if you're storing the image URL/Paths in a database, make sure both applications have access to this database.

Comment: You can also get away with a symlink/junction link on the folder.

Comment: If you ask me, send the files to an object storage system like Amazon s3

Comment: How can i directly call the images in my blade file? I try using {{url('link/to/my/path')}} but is not working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `config/filesystems.php` create new disk inside `disks` array:

```
 'your-disk' => [
            'driver' => 'local',
            'root' => 'C:\\path\\to\\your\\folder',
        ],
// using an extra \ for escaping
```

using the `Storage` facade to deal with your file, example, to put a new file on the `download` folder inside your disk:

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Storage;
 
Storage::disk('your-disk')->put('file.pdf', $file);
```

fore more details, read the [Documentation.](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/filesystem)

Comment: it's in the documentation, either by `Storage::disk('your_disk')->download('file.pdf')` or by using url() instead of download ()

Comment: How can i directly call the images or use symlink to call it. I did try to use symlink but i had a hard time understanding it.